# Spinner com um icone de chamada

Tags: java, android, spinners

Olá,estou tentando fazer um spinner com as opções: "Aberto Hoje" e "Não importa".

No meu layout, não quero que apareça nada escrito e sim um icone de relógio, que quando clicado carregue a lista do spinner.

Coloquei a imagem no background do spinner.

Acontece que ela expande conforme selecionado a opção da lista, será que tem como deixá-la de tamanho fixo?

E também a outra dúvida é será que a lista com as opções pode ser adicionada somente na posição 1, porque como não sei isso, estou adicionando o primeiro elemento da lista como "" para que no layout fique somente a imagem.

Tentei colocar como listheader, mas tb não deu certo.
Muito obrigada!
O que estou utilizando:

```
No Layout:
 <Spinner
android:id="@+id/spinner3"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:layout_gravity="center"
android:gravity="center_horizontal"
android:scrollIndicators="end"
android:textAlignment="center"
android:background="@drawable/local" />

No código:
horario = new ArrayList<>();
horario.add("");
horario.add("Aberto Hoje");
horario.add("Não importa");
adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(getApplication(), android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item, horario);
    spinnerhora.setAdapter(adapter);
```

Comment: Tu pode colocar um imageview em baixo do spinner. Antes do usuário clicar no spinner deixe ele invisível.

Comment: Oi Tiago, é uma boa idéia, mas como eu faço (em código) para que quando o usuario clique no ImageView abra o spinner?

Answer (score 0):

> No Layout

```
<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">
    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/image3"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:src="@drawable/imagem"/>
    <Spinner
        android:id="@+id/spinner3"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:scrollIndicators="end"
        android:textAlignment="center"
        android:background="@drawable/local"
        android:visibility="gone" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

> No código

```
Spinner spinner3 = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinner3);
ImageView image3 = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.image3);

ArrayList horario = new ArrayList<>();    
horario.add("Aberto Hoje");
horario.add("Não importa");
ArrayAdapter adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(getApplication(), android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item, horario);
spinner3.setAdapter(adapter);

image3.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    public void onClick(View v) {
        spinner3.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    }
});
```